# Linux WAR file deployment error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jpos

I am new to Jersey and tomcat deployment.

I am trying to interface my webapp with an Epson TM82 printer.

However I am getting the First Error as shown

[image: Fisrt error]

when I try to access locally after deploying WAR file and upon refreshing I got another Second Error:

[image: Second error]

What is interesting is that when I run the deployment using Eclipse Java EE, the code runs and the printer is able to print.

I have checked

> java -XshowSettings:properties

and library path and class path shows the correct location of the libraries and .so files.

May I know what is going on?

Comment: what are you using? tomcat or  glassfish??? glassfish and tomcat are different servers

Comment: he is using glassfish as i saw in image (click on First Error)

Comment: @Monty, but the tab title in that picture also says Apache Tomcat...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the library (jar) is bundled in your WAR file under the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check java.library.path

Sample :

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {      
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        System.loadLibrary("jp_co_epson_upos_firm_FirmNativeAccess");
    }
}
```

> Make sure there is jp_co_ epson_upos_firm_FirmNativeAccess.dll in the
>   path.

If you installed EPSON Java POS : Uninstall is completely and install is again.